# How to implement a type safe, phantom types based builder in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

The idea is to allow a call to the .build() method only upon having all the mandatory parameters filled. So the constructor should be taught to do some validation.

Comment: If you wish that all parameters would be required, then just don't allow optional parameters. Or maybe I don't understand your question. Could you provide your code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

> If I understand you correctly, you have some kind of `builder` class, which by default doesn't have all the required parameters. And that class has a method, which updates its state. Only when all required parameters are set, only then `build` method should be available.

So first of all, we have `T` type which partial (all properties are optional).

On each update, we should return a new instance with type `T & Record<K, T[K]>` - it means optional `T` + one non-optional property.

Finally, we can use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to allow `build` only when `T extends Required<T>`.

So the final solution:

```
function createBuilder<T>(initialData: T) {
    return {
        update: <K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]) => {
            return createBuilder<T & Record<K, T[K]>>({
                ...initialData,
                [key]: value
            })
        },
        build: (() => {
            // 
        }) as T extends Required<T> ? () => boolean : undefined
    }
}

const builder1 = createBuilder<Partial<{
    key1: string,
    key2: number
}>>({})
builder1.build()
// Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'

const builder2 = builder1.update('key1', 'abc')
builder2.build()
// Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'

const builder3 = builder2.update('key2', 10)
builder3.build()
// No error
```

Hovewer, there is no point having this logic. If you can statically update the object, you probably can set all properties in the constructor.